# special cite-style i need to confirm

Tags: bibliographies

(this is my first post in this forum, so i'am trieng to stick to the guideline)

I need to quote in a special Form, showed as desktop-picture here:
[image]

I searched the web and found this:

```
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\setcitestyle{square,aysep={}}
```

So if I write all Authors in capitals, it kinda look alike, but not entirely. Above all the first letter of the Author's name, is a bit bigger then the rest of the name, which i can't fix in my code.

I know that you can design a own cite-style somehow, but if i look at the guides there is no way i can do that as a tex-novice. So I would like to ask if there is an easy way or some kind of tex-command to fullfill that design, especially with this slightly bigger first letter.

Here is my flawed design for comparison:

[image]

(I didn't find an existing thread helping myself with a lack of tex-skills. I hope this thread confirms to the forum-rules, thanks beforehand.)

Comment: It is much easier to customise citation and bibiographies if you use  `biblatex`, which has an `author-year` style.

Comment: You may want to look for bibliography style files that implement the citation style of the journal *Econometrica*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention Allweyer and Becker you are probably looking for a citation style fitting to the journal WIRTSCHAFTSINFORMATIK and every newer version like "Springer Basic" won't fit. If that is the case perhaps you might want to take a look at udesoftec.bst with the appropriate captions and configurations defined in udesoftec.cls around line 600 of package udesoftec (http://mirror.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/udesoftec). 
The bst was designed for this, but with additional LaTeX-command-level-configuration in mind for quick adjustments, because bst-changes are really hard.

Note: this is a package with major contributions by myself. But as i just started this bst, because I was having this very problem I feel I should post this solution nevertheless.

**Update:**

As I tried to produce an MWE I saw that the option to have "S. " or "p. " preceeding the page number was removed from the bst. Sorry.

**Update 2:**

As of **pkg:udesoftec v1.4.1 2014/05/27** a separate .sty file is available which uses natbib/hyperref/hypehenat/csquotes/scrbase and configures all the labels and cite-specific commands for the class:

```
\usepackage{udesoftec-bst}
```

(Due to a RequirePackage{hyperref} this package should be loaded last to prevent option clash.)

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. I can compile your file with my latex-distribution so I think I can integrate it in my own file, and maybe also change the colour to black and add the serife to the letters. My deeply thanks for your work on this package and especially for sharing it! (Vielen lieben Dank!)

Comment: You're welcome. The update to the answer might be misleading though: you can of course use \cite[p. 34-35]{Source.2014} but initially it was intended to just include \cite[34-35]{Source.2014} in order to have the "p." defined automatically based on the language.